# Command to get the console output of last 'n' jobs triggered in Jenkins

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins

Is there a way to get the console out put of last 10 jobs triggerd in jenkins through command line? Currently I am using curl command for last build triggered like below
curl --user 'username:password' "https://URL/jobname/lastBuild/?"

Is there any such commands for last 'n' jobs triggered?

Answer (score -1):

I don't know how you can perform that by one command.
But this plugin may be useful:
https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Multijob+Plugin